# What is the probability of having the same (binary) datasets?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, data-analysis

Suppose we have $m$ binary data points as an outcome of a specific experiment, so the outcomes of those points are fixed. We save our data in a file of $m$ points having value $0$ or $1$. (for example our data is $0101$)

Then we damage a subset of the datafile such that $n<m$ outcomes are randomly changed. We are aware of the fact that $n$ bits **could** have changed.

. We know which $n$ could take a new value (or keeps the same value). For example if we damage our $0101$ where we know that only the first bit randomly changes, the result could be $0101$ or $1101$.

My question is:

Can we say that this probability can be calculated by
$$p(\text{binary datasets are the same})=\frac{2^m - 2^n}{2^m} $$

Now alternatively, suppose that our datapoints have $r \in \{2,3,4,...\}$ possible outcomes. There are $m$ datapoints and $n < m$ missing datapoints. Can we say that the probability that our datasets (the complete one and the incomplete one) are the same is expressed as follows:

$$ p(\text{datasets are the same}| r,m,n) = \frac{r^m-r^n}{r^m}$$

Comment: On the basis of the information given, you do not have enough information to calculate the probability that the datasets are the same. You can calculate $p(X_1 = 0 \wedge X_2 = 0 \wedge \ldots \wedge X_n = 0)$ (where $X_i$ is 0 if the ith vulnerable is unchanged, and 1 if it changes) given $p(X_1 = 0), p(X_2 = 0), \ldots, p(X_n = 0)$, but the only information you've given us is that the "*outcomes are randomly changed*" - i.e. that $p(X_1 = 0)$ etc. *exist*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're comparing the $2^{m-n}$ certain bits with another $2^{m-n}$ bits.  If those bits are completely random (either the original $2^{m-n}$ or the second $2^{m-n}$, or both), the probability that they are the same is $1/2^{m-n}$.

EDIT:
For the new question, where you have $n$ bits that are changed randomly, the probability that the new dataset is the same as the original (which I presume is what you mean by "this probability") is $1/2^n$. And for general $r$ it would be $1/r^n$.

Comment: No, what i mean is this:

Suppose we have $m$ binary data points and we 'destroy' the data of $n < m$ points such that the outcomes of those $n$ points are randomly changed. That means we are certain about the outcomes of $m-n$ points and we are not certain about the $n$ randomly changed point. How much information do we have now?

And what about data that isn't binary, but have 3 or $r$ possible outcomes per datapoint?

Comment: Do you know which bits were affected?  And what about the $m-n$ bits you are comparing to?  Are they random?  You really need to make your question much clearer.

Comment: I updated my question